# How to apply a function/method to multiple variables?

Tags: python, function, methods

Often in my code I need to apply the same function or method to multiple variables. Traditionally, I do so as follows:

```
begin_range = row[0].replace(' ', '')
end_range = row[1].strip().replace(' ', '')
```

or

```
begin_range, end_range = row[0].replace(' ', ''), row[1].strip().replace(' ', '')
```

Is there a way to call the function/method for multiple variables in a way that the function is only written once?

Comment: Yes. Write a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible in lots of ways!

The simplest one could be something like follows:

```
def usual_task(rows):
    return rows[0].replace(' ', ''), rows[1].strip().replace(' ', '')
```

and simply use it any place else as follows:

```
begin_range, end_range = usual_task(row)
```

If there is a pattern on remained data, you could apply much more complex function or other stuffs to keep you code simple and easy to read!